# Opa 1.01 : how to prevent opa from running it's own mongo database

Tags: mongodb, opa, database

I've switched to opa 1.0.1, and it seems that now opa install it's own mongodb in ~/.opa/mongo. Apaprently, this mongo instance is runned on the default 27017 port.

How can I prevent opa from running this new mongodb, and instead use the one already running on the default port on my server ?

Or at least, can I change the default port used by the new mondodb ? I've tried the option

```
--db-remote:mydb localhost:4242
```

But it doas not seems to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, use the `--db-remote host:port` startup option to prevent Opa using the ~/.opa/mongo db.

If you have only one db declared in your app, don't add the ":mydb" suffix.

Comment: Thanks. It's working ;) Is it possible to use the opa integrated database (~/.opa/mongo) with different opa applications ? Won't there be also conflict on the database port ? Or does opa launch the database for the first application and automatically re used it for the second application ?

Comment: Yes several applications can you use the ~/.opa/mongo database. The database will be started only the first time.